# Не добавляется данные ajax codeigniter

Tags: ajax, база-данных, codeigniter, sql

Подскажите. Делаю добавление данных аяксом без перезагрузки. Добавление происходит. Но он добавляет почему-то вместе введенных данных ноли. Вроде данные не доходят до модели. Что я сделал не так? Почему ноли добавляются?

отображение:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="">
```

скрипт:

```
var text = $("#text").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
     data: {'text': text}
      success: function(add){

        alert ('Выполнено!');
      },
      error: function(add){
        alert ('Ошибка!');
        }

    });
```

контроллер:

```
if ($param1 == 'add')   {
    $this->rut_model->create_text_add($param2);
}
```

модель:

```
function create_text_add($id = '')  {
    $data['text']   =   $this->input->post('text');
    $data['id'] =   $id;    
    $this->db->insert('post' , $data);
    }
```